# Real vs complex norm for polynomials

Tags: polynomials, normed-spaces

Let $d \in \mathbb{N}$. We denote by $C_{d}$ the best (smallest) constant satisfying that
$$ \sup{\{ |P(z)| \colon z \in \mathbb{D} \}} \leq C_{d} \, \sup{\{ |P(x)| \colon x \in [-1,1] \}} $$
for every polynomial $P$ of degree $\leq d$ with real coefficients.

I would like to know whether these constants are known, or the best known estimations for them (with references).

Right now, I am only aware of the paper of Erdös: Some remarks on polynomials (1947).

Comment: Is $\Bbb D$ the unit disc in the complex plane?

Comment: Here is an estimate (Thm 2.1).  I don't know if it is best. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021904583710609

Comment: To Arthur: Yes, $\mathbb{D} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \colon |z| < 1 \}$. I should have pointed it out... To John M, Thanks for the reference. Actually it is from that paper where I got the reference to Erdös' paper (which is used in the proof of Th 2.1)

Comment: Well you can try using MathSciNet to peruse recent papers that quote either of those two papers.  MathOverflow may be a better place for that question.

Comment: @JohnM Yes, I tried MathSciNet but I was not very successful... I had not realized of the differences between Overflow and Stackexchange, but now that you mention this probably fits better with Overflow. Thanks for your interest!